# Stripe business profile is not showing on request body

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I'm in test mode, I create a custom connected account successfully using JavaScript in frontend and PHP in backend.

The account created successfully but for some reason, the business profile is not showing on request body (I see this in stripe log in dashboard).

I see a warning message before form submition:
`business_profile` is not a recognized parameter

For your reference, here’s the API coding I used when I did my test: 
https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create?lang=php#create_account-business_profile

**JavaScript**

```
const accountResult = await stripe.createToken('account', {
    business_type: 'company',
    company: {...},
    business_profile: {
      mcc: "5812",
      support_email: "test@example.com",
      url: "https://example.com",
    },
    tos_shown_and_accepted: true,
});
```

**PHP**

```
// ...
$account = \Stripe\Account::create([
    "country" => "FR",
    "type" => "custom",
    "account_token" => $account_token,
]);
// ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stripe.createToken` doesn't take a `business_profile` value, nor does it manage `Stripe\Account` objects at all - it creates [a `Stripe\Token`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/object). You'll have to update that information via a separate call to the Stripe API. The parameters it *does* take [are documented here](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-create-token):

> name, address_line1,address_line2, address_city, address_state, address_zip, address_country, currency